# Cannot delete file with 'Storage::delete'

Tags: php, laravel

I cannot delete file by using laravel `Storage::delete` fuction.

My image store code is :

```
$logoPath = $request->file('logo')->store('images','public');
```

It store image at

```
storage/app/public/images/0HHJ5DygYUXuLC5dgu14KJTPvCEaxhISV8tpb4Pq.png
```

I use `Storage::delete('/images/0HHJ5DygYUXuLC5dgu14KJTPvCEaxhISV8tpb4Pq.png');` to delete it. But it not working;

What I have tried is:

```
Storage::delete(asset('storage/images/0HHJ5DygYUXuLC5dgu14KJTPvCEaxhISV8tpb4Pq.png'));

Storage::delete(storage_path('images/0HHJ5DygYUXuLC5dgu14KJTPvCEaxhISV8tpb4Pq.png'));`
```

Even I try to delete some picture at public folder. It's not working.

```
Storage::delete(public_path('images/logo3.png'));
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Does your error logs show something? It might be a permissions issue. Are you sure the file exists at that path?

Comment: What is the error shown?

Comment: I would try `Storage::disk('public')->delete($logoPath)` or `Storage::delete($logoPath)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what works for me, hopefully it works for you too:

```
Storage::delete('public/images/0HHJ5DygYUXuLC5dgu14KJTPvCEaxhISV8tpb4Pq.png');
```

Comment: no worries man! I had some problems with it at first, couldn't figure out what path it needed

Answer (score 0):

The [delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#deleting-files) method accepts a single filename to remove from the disk:

```
Storage::delete('public/images/filename.png');
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the php way of deleting a file. unlink() function.

```
$file = $request->input('filename');
unlink(storage_path('app/public/images/' . $file));
```